# How to adjust resolution to display only in portrait mode for both phones and tablet devices?

Tags: c#, android, ios, resolution, unity-ui

I am facing an issue where I'm able to adjust the resolution for different phones like Android and iOS but not for tablet devices.

Is there any way to set it, for all kinds of devices, to display only in portrait mode?

Comment: Please don't tag a question UnityScript (an old JavaScript-like language that Unity no longer supports) when the code is actually written in C#. I've edited your question to correct some code formatting, grammar, and punctuation. Can you verify that the edits correctly convey your intended question? It looks like this code is actually trying to adjust for a safe area, not change resolution or enforce portrait mode as implied in your text.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I'll make the changes.